# getBulkProperties very slow

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Following the advice given on one of my other questions ([Get a list of all objects from loaded model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47571195/get-a-list-of-all-objects-from-loaded-model/)), I added this code on my application to retrieve all properties from all objects:

```
function onGeometryLoadedEvent(viewer) {
    var dbIds = Object.keys(
        viewer.model.getData().instanceTree.nodeAccess.dbIdToIndex
    );

    this.viewer.model.getBulkProperties(
        dbIds,
        {
            propFilter: false,
            ignoreHidden: true
        },
        (objects) => console.log(objects),
        () => console.log('error')
    )
}
```

It correctly shows all the objects. The problem is it takes A LOT of time to complete (+1 minute), even for a model with just 10,000 objects.

Is this normal?

I really need the list of objects with their categories, I have to sort them after getting them to present a list of all the available categories and properties to the user.

I know I can use the Model Derivatives API, but I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Note that when you list **all** elements on the model it will include those that are not visible, like categories. If you need only elements on the model, then you need the leaf of the model. This [article described it](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/enumerating-leaf-nodes-viewer) and the source code is below:

```
function getAllLeafComponents(viewer, callback) {
    var cbCount = 0; // count pending callbacks
    var components = []; // store the results
    var tree; // the instance tree

    function getLeafComponentsRec(parent) {
        cbCount++;
        if (tree.getChildCount(parent) != 0) {
            tree.enumNodeChildren(parent, function (children) {
                getLeafComponentsRec(children);
            }, false);
        } else {
            components.push(parent);
        }
        if (--cbCount == 0) callback(components);
    }
    viewer.getObjectTree(function (objectTree) {
        tree = objectTree;
        var allLeafComponents = getLeafComponentsRec(tree.getRootId());
    });
}
```

Now with the `.getBulkProperties` you can specify which property you want, so something like **Category**, right? So specify that, [as shown at this article](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/getbulkproperties-method) and used with the above `.getAllLeafComponent` function:

```
getAllLeafComponents(viewer, function (dbIds) {
   viewer.model.getBulkProperties(dbIds, ['Category'],
     function(elements){
       // ToDo here
       // this will only include leaf with Category property
   })
})
```

And I would expect this to be faster than your original code, as I'm filtering elements and properties.